# Taudem Resources

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, geoprocessing, taudem

As I frequently deal with hydrology, I've heard [Taudem](http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5.0/index.html) mentioned quite a few times.

I'm finding all sorts of information, but much of it is dated for use with previous versions. In addition, the current build doesn't support gui interaction with Arc10, which might not be a hindrance to many of you, but certainly raises the barrier of entry for many others.

Given that it seems like such a powerful tool, I would have imagined seeing some more social resources dedicated to it. But I haven't. Is my search-foo bad, and is there some sort of Taudem enclave out there that I just can't find? Or is it just that something of this sort doesn't exist yet?

The reason I'm looking to use taudem is that Arc10 and ArcHydro still seem a bit hairy at times.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the links to the current version (5.0) of TauDEM.
http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5.0/index.html
It is fully functional on Arc 9.3.1, but not 10.0.
However, you can use Tau from the Command Prompt.  The code is fairly readable, and they give examples to try.
- see: http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5.0/TauDEM5CommandLineGuide.pdf

As for your comment on *crowdsourcing* this product:

From Dr. Tarboton's USU Research Site

> At version 10 ArcGIS no longer
>   supports the Visual Basic 6.0 language
>   used to code the GUI that helps
>   specify the input in an easy to use
>   way. I have not had time (or funding)
>   to rewrite the interface in a newer
>   language. Offers to do this, or to
>   fund this, are welcome.

Open Source would be less likely since this was created in academia with grant funding, which sometimes hold onto intellectually-derived property like glue!